# Material SeekBar style

Tags: android

I have an activity with "Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" style. This activity has SeekBar.
I want to use Material style for this SeekBar.

My v-21/style.xml listing:

```
<style name="SeekBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.SeekBar" />
```

But I have a problem: seekbar is green by default, and on touch background become yellow. (screenshot is here ).

[image]
How can I change this style?

**UPD:**
I replaced "Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" style by this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

Now SeekBar looks good.

Comment: where is your code??

Comment: I am sorry, what code do you need? I only have <SeekBar ... /> in my layout.xml and <style name="SeekBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.SeekBar" /> in style.xml. Nothing else.

Comment: So whats your question?